# scss file does not contain a default export (Gatsby and Sass)

Tags: reactjs, sass, module, gatsby

I know my path is correct because it takes the styles if I don't add module to the extension. I'm working from a bootcamp which is over a year and a half old and trying to research any potential breaking changes, but having no such luck.

Says link is not defined and my scss file has no default export.

Thanks

```
.link {
  color: green;
}
```

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import headerStyles from "../styles/header.module.scss"

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link className={headerStyles.link} to="/">
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import headerStyles from "../styles/header.module.scss"

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link className={headerStyles.link} to="/">
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 12):

After updating gatsby to version 3, I was in the same situation.

`* as sth` would be fine if you want to import an entire module.

```
import * as headerStyles from "../styles/header.module.scss"
```

Comment: It seems a bug. Please watch the issue: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/30040

Comment: It's not a bug, it’s working as intended: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/#css-modules-are-imported-as-es-modules

Answer (score 2):

```
import { link } from "../styles/header.module.scss"
```

Fixed it moments after posting with destructuring.

Comment: would love for a default export solution as to not need to destructure each property individually.

Answer (score -2):

```js
import * as headerStyles import './header.module.scss'
```

Comment: Code-only comments are discouraged, please explain why this would work - especially since it's syntactically incorrect.